# Is there a way to refresh Power Automate Instant Flows in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, power-automate

I have been developing a few Instant Flows in Microsoft Teams using the "For a selected message" Trigger, but they all seem to take ages to become available in MS Teams once they are created.

I have tried:

- Closing MS Teams
- Closing MS Teams via Task Manager

Neither of those was enough for the Trigger to become available, as the Flow is not an option when I select a message and go to More Actions.

Comment: We created an instant flow having trigger action "For a selected message" and are able to see the flow for any message selected https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkrTg.png . Could you please refresh/update your MS teams by clearing cache and check if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution to be clearing the cache of Microsoft Teams, which consists of the folders at this file path:

%appdata%\Microsoft\Teams

Deleting all of these folders is not ideal, as you will lose your settings and custom backgrounds, so I deleted each of them one-by-one until I found the IndexedDB folder refreshed the actions when it is deleted.

Steps to refresh Instant Flows in MS Teams:

1. Close MS Teams
2. Open File Explorer (win+e)
3. Copy and paste %appdata%\Microsoft\Teams into the Address bar
4. Delete the IndexedDB folder
5. Start MS Teams